# Twitter4j search by user name and user bio

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

I am using twitter4j library to access twitter api.
I can sucessfully retrieve information about user by user screen name (like @username) but I wonder is it possible to search by user display name (like 'Firstname Lastname')

Also is it possible to search within user description by some keyword, any advices are warmly appricated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can get along with [`searchUsers`](http://twitter4j.org/en/javadoc/twitter4j/api/UserMethods.html#searchUsers%28java.lang.String,%20int%29).

Comment: @codebrickie How do you get the exact user from twitter using First Name and Last Name